# Load meteor for the main domain and php code on subdomain with nginx

Tags: php, meteor, nginx, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have a challenge that I can't figure out how to solve.
I a DigitalOcean VPS running CentOS7. Here I host a domain, e.q. www.example.com.
I'm running nginx right now on it. It used to be Apache but I could not figure it out how to make the websockets reversed proxy, for meteor work with Apache.

Now in Nginx I created a vhost configuration to load for the main domain, www.example.com and example.com, from a meteor server that runs with pm2-meteor:

```
    server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy; # we enable SPDY here
    server_name www.example.com; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate

    root /var/www/html/example/bundle; # irrelevant
    index index.html; # irrelevant

    ssl_certificate /etc/httpd/ssl/example/example.crt; # full path to SSL certificate and CA certificate concatenated together
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/httpd/ssl/example/example.key; # full path to SSL key

    # performance enhancement for SSL
    ssl_stapling off;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    # safety enhancement to SSL: make sure we actually use a safe cipher
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';

    # config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
    # to avoid ssl stripping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_stripping#SSL_stripping
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";

    # If your application is not compatible with IE <= 10, this will redirect visitors to a page advising a browser update
    # This works because IE 11 does not present itself as MSIE anymore
    #if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE" ) {
    #    return 303 https://browser-update.org/update.html;
    #}

    # pass all requests to Meteor
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP

        # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
                                                                                                                                    45,1          Top
```

I'm running the meteor server on 4001 port.
Ok, this works perfectly for meteor. My problem now is that I want to create a vhost for a subdomain, payment.example.com, which will load larval 5. 
Normally I want this subdomain to load over HTTPS also.
How on earth can I do this without loading the default nginx vhost settings or the domain vhost which loads meteor?
I can't figure out a way to make it work. This is the payment subdomain virtual host I'm trying to make and it's not working:

```
    server {
listen 431 ssl spdy; # we enable SPDY here
listen [::]:431 ipv6only=on default_server;
server_name payment.example.ro; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate
root /var/www/html/example/payment/;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log;

ssl_certificate /etc/httpd/ssl/example/example.crt; # full path to SSL certificate and CA certificate concatenated together
ssl_certificate_key /etc/httpd/ssl/example/example.key; # full path to SSL key

# performance enhancement for SSL
ssl_stapling off;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;

# safety enhancement to SSL: make sure we actually use a safe cipher
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';

# config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
# to avoid ssl stripping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_stripping#SSL_stripping
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    location / {
                root /var/www/html/example/payment/;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
               }
    location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                }
```

}

Now when I load payment.example.com I load the meteor reversed proxy.
Any suggestions or ideas on what to do to make this work. Is this even possible?
Do I have to put it in a subfolder rather that subdomain? I prefer the subdomain...

Thank you guy!

Comment: Are you using [SNI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni)?

Comment: Ahh yes, I think I do. I run nginx -V and it show that it is installed.

Comment: You have `payment.example.ro` on port 431 and marked as `default_server`. Three typos?